# Использование модератором банов при взаимной словесной перепалке

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, модерация, чат, бан

Модератор активно участвует в словесной перепалке с участником в чате, игнорирует просьбы прекратить это, при попытках возразить без стеснения пользуется банхаммером и удаляет безобидные сообщения. Свои сообщения с беспочвенными обвинениями модератор оставляет и продолжает писать без возможности участника парировать, тем самым провицируя дальнейшую перепалку.

Что делать в подобной ситуации? Имеет ли модератор право использовать банхаммер в споре?

Comment: Я бы дополнил, что ситуация осложняется тем, что этот кто-то - кандидат на попадание в модераторский состав, и прослеживается конфликт интересов модератора - недопустить неудобные вопросы и мнения к "власти".

Comment: @Kromster вы про какую-то конкретную ситуацию говорите? на всякий случай, в той конкретной ситуации, которую вы подразумеваете, первоначальный бан участнику прилетел не от второй стороны спора.

Comment: @PashaPash я говорю про абстрактную ситуацию (как попросил Николас). Она касается и 1 и 2 и 3 банов. Все три бана были выписаны кем - модераторами. Кому - неудобному кандидату. Имхо это важное дополнение к вопросу топикстартера.

Comment: @Kromster ок, но в вопросе под модератором и под тем, кто поставил бан, подразумевается явно один человек. Т.е. я рад, что ситуация чисто гипотетическая и у нас такого не происходило.

Comment: Просто к слову, все написанно выше не имеет отношения к реальной жизни. Я бы хотел поинтересоваться, не против ли вы, если я перепишу вопрос так, чтобы он был более реалистичным? В текущей формулировке данный вопрос следует удалить, честно. Он не имеет никакого отношения к реальности, очерняет модераторский состав и запугивает участников. Такого не было и не будет в нашем сообществе.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что данная ситуация не может возникнуть в сообществе, как результат, любой ответ не будет отражать реальности, хотя может быть истолкован как данность.

Comment: Простите, вероятно, вы описали ситуацию с какого–то другого сайта. У нас нет никакого «банхаммер». Пожалуйста, задайте ваш вопрос на том сайте, где подобная ситуация может быть.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky глупости какие. Вопрос абстрактный, можно свести к "кто устережёт сторожей?" Нарушение правил со стороны модератора технически возможно, его пресечение из-за высоких полномочий нарушителя может быть здорово затруднено. Участникам стоит знать, как поступать при столкновении с подобными проблемами. Утверждая "у нас такого не может быть", вы намекаете, что у вас нет решения, что серьёзная уязвимость местной общественной системы. Что не добавляет ощущения безопасности обычным участникам.

Comment: А комментарии, добавляющие к гипотетическому вопросу отфонарные детали, предлагаю удалить, как не имеющие к нему отношения. Понятно, что вопрос вдохновлён конкретным случаем, но он не о нём. И не просто так.

Comment: @D-side Но у нас нет таких проблем! Такой ситуации не может быть! Этот вопрос сравни тому, что мы будем делать, если я завтра стану бетменом, который начнет посещать каждого, кто плохо относится к новичкам, а еще лучше, всех тех, кто не отвечает на сайте! Давайте это обсудим, испугаемся меня–бетмена и отстраним от работы, на всякий случай, а то вдруг «бетмен и все такое».

Comment: @D-side Я начал переписывать и понял, что если их удалить, то ничего не останется.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky "даже если вам некого поджарить сегодня, надо подумать о будущем". С вами-то как раз всё просто, вы сотрудник компании Stack Overflow, владеющей этим сайтом, и являетесь высшей инстанцией, несогласие с которой можно преодолеть смирением или уходом (или всем вместе). Но это техническая особенность. Я же об особенности общественной. Модераторы высшей инстанцией не являются.

Comment: @D-side Вы можете написать в компанию, ген. директору, например, и попросить меня отстранить. Более того, если ваши аргументы будут убедительными и я ничего не смогу поделать с ними (в плане, изменения себя так, чтобы не нарушать правила), уверяю, мне хватит общечеловеческих качеств отстраниться. Что касается общественности, обсуждая данный вопрос, мы приписываем людям то, чем они не обладают. Это провокация.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я верю в вас. И в наших модераторов тоже верю. Но мне немножко спокойнее находиться в сообществе, зная, что правила для всех и что меры пресечения есть и против модераторов, при необходимости. До мер пресечения ваших нарушений (раз уж вы предложили гипотезу) доводить не вижу смысла, т. к. у компании Stack Overflow чисто технически абсолютный контроль над сайтом, а вы её сотрудник. Если я потеряю веру в компанию, то активничать на её сайтах у меня не будет резона.

Comment: @D-side Огромное спасибо за доверие. У модератора можно забрать «ромб» в любое время. Любого участника можно заблокировать. У нас уже был инцидент. Думаю, вы помните его результат. С тех пор ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky помню. Но актуальности и онтопичности вопроса это не отменяет. Если это дубликат -- давайте отметим. Но я не припоминаю похожих вопросов. Ввиду своей чистой гипотетичности (которую можно обозначить явно, кстати), вопрос являться провокацией не может.

Comment: @D-side Я бы с радостью написал в двух словах ответ на вопрос «Что делать, если модератор нарушает правила в чате или на сайте? Что делать если модератор использует свои расширенные возможности не по назначению, с корыстью?» Данный вопрос, к слову, нельзя свести к нему.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а по-моему, можно (хотя высшая инстанция по этому вопросу -- ТС, и наши мнения об этом не так важны). Но сделать по теме канонический вопрос тоже неплохой план, как минимум он ни от кого не зависит.

Answer (score 7):

#### Выйти из спора и вынести проблему на обсуждение на Мете, для начала, без конкретики

Спорить или препираться с модератором - себе дороже. Лучше этого избегать. У него свое мнение - у вас свое. У него есть банхаммер - у вас нет.

Наверное лучше всего выйти из спора пока не "прилетело" и запилить вопрос анологичный этому (как и посоветовал Николас). Если модераторский состав вас не поддержит и ничего не сделает - значит вам в эту компанию не надо - время строить свой "Лунный модуль с блэкджеком и куртизанками"

Comment: Минуса прошу обосновывать в комментариях или своем варианте ответа

Comment: @Kromster Подозреваю, проголосовавший против не одобряет всесилия **правила №0**. :-)

Comment: Обосновываю свой минус. Один из основных столпов Stack Overflow это то, что сайт управляется сообществом. С этой позиции, споры с модератором не должны отличаться от споров с рядовыми участниками, у которых банхаммеров нет. Если отличается -- значит, управления сообществом не существует, точка. Выходить из спора значит закрывать глаза на проблему вместо её решения.

Comment: @D-side запостите это ответом?

Comment: @Kromster поскольку вопрос закрыли, нет, более не имею на то возможности.

Comment: @D-side а если переоткроют?

Comment: @alexolut если черновик сохранился -- допишу через какое-то время. Если не сохранился -- не знаю. Там много было :(

Comment: @D-side Ваш выход!

Comment: @D-side Жду ответа. :)

Answer (score 6):

Для начала, как и в любой конфликтной ситуации в интернете, надо закрыть браузер и заняться чем-нибудь другим. Через пару дней попытаться взглянуть на ситуацию глазами модератора.

Вполне может оказаться что взаимную словесную перепалку видел только один участник (вы), а модератор видел флейм, оффтопик и прочие нарушения правил сайта. В таком случае делать больше ничего не надо.

В противном случае надо писать сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact (эти сообщения потом попадут к Nicolas Chabanovsky).